# Time convert to timestamp

Tags: java, datetime, timestamp-with-timezone

I have a log in timeformat

> 31/Mar/2013:17:03:30 -0700

I want to convert it into a timestamp here -70 in timezone. How can I do that?

```
try {
    String time = myMap.get("timestamp");
    String splitTime[] = time.split("-");//input Timestamp 31/Mar/2013:17:03:30 -0700
    Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss").parse(splitTime[0]);
    myMap.put("timestamp", String.valueOf(new Long(date.getTime() / 1000)));
} catch (ParseException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

How do I use this timezone?

Comment: try `"dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z"` and you can parse the whole string without splitting it up manually.

Comment: @vikingsteve - pls post as an answer

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z").parse(s);
```

note that it will only parse `/Mar/` if your default language is English, otherwise use

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US).parse(s);
```

Comment: An addition `date.getTime()` would give it in `long`.

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use that time zone information to subtract/add that much time to your date:

```
String time = myMap.get("timestamp");
String splitTime[] = time.split("-");//input Timestamp 31/Mar/2013:17:03:30 -0700
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:HH:mm:ss").parse(splitTime[0]);

long timestamp = date.getTime() / 1000;  ///datetime in seconds

long timezonehour = Long.parseLong(splitTime[1].substring(0,1));   // 07
long timezoneminutes = Long.parseLong(splitTime[1].substring(2,3));  // 00

timezonehour +=  timezoneminutes/60;

long timezone_seconds = (timezonehour/60)/60;   // in seconds

timestamp += timezone_seconds // final computed value
```

I know this looks ugly but can't help further.